# Print receipt in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, thermal-printer

[image: receipt]

I am trying to print the above receipt using vb.net. However, as seen in the image, the amount figure appears on a new line. What am I doing wrong?

Below is the code I use:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

        Dim offset As Integer = 15
    Dim itemdesc As String = "Item".PadRight(30)
        Dim Pricedesc As String = "Price".PadRight(8)
        Dim qtydesc As String = "Qty".PadRight(5)
        Dim amtdesc As String = "Amount"
        Dim descline As String = itemdesc + Pricedesc + qtydesc + amtdesc
        e.Graphics.DrawString(descline, New Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 25, 100 + offset)
        offset += 10
    Dim startx As Integer = 25
        Dim starty As Integer = 100

        Dim font As New Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
        Dim item As String
        Dim price As String
        Dim qty As String
        Dim amount As String

    Dim productline As String
        For k As Integer = 0 To dgvSales.RowCount - 2

            item = dgvSales.Rows(k).Cells(1).Value.ToString.PadRight(30)
            price = dgvSales.Rows(k).Cells(3).Value.ToString.PadRight(8)
            qty = dgvSales.Rows(k).Cells(4).Value.ToString.PadRight(5)
            amount = dgvSales.Rows(k).Cells(5).Value.ToString
            productline = item + price + qty + amount
            e.Graphics.DrawString(productline, font, Brushes.Black, startx, starty + offset)
            offset += 20

        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:thermal-printer]?

Comment: Try printing a single character in that column to see if it will render in the right place?

Comment: @halfer i tried printing single character in the amount column but still prints in the next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three possibilities:

- Your column qty (column idx 4) contains a string that has a newline in it. If this is the case, you can just `Trim()` the value before joining the values.
- Your column amount contains many spaces, or begins with a newline character. If this is the case, you can also fix it by using `Trim()`, this time on the variable `amount` before joining the values.
- It's something else that I haven't thought of yet :).

Comment: To downvoter: please provide a small comment in the future to indicate what could be improved.

Comment: I used Trim() for both qty and amount as below but did not work. qty = 
    Trim(dgvSales.Rows(k).Cells(4).Value.ToString.PadRight(5))
            amount = Trim(dgvSales.Rows(k).Cells(5).Value.ToString)

Comment: I used Trim(). It worked. Thank you for your help. Means a lot to me.

Comment: Happy to help :).

Comment: @Mr47  and Sonam,,....  Its helped a lot to print my receipt. But instead of English fonts I am using other font **Malayalam** (Indian language) through Google Input Tools.  Via this codes its not printing in proper columns.  Becoz its not Fixed width fonts.  Any solution?